# Bootstrap 4 - trying to keep flex wrapped images overflowing previous column

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want a left column with a larger image and a right column with a wrapped list of smaller thumbnails. When I resize the window smaller, eventually the thumbnails overflow the left column. I want to keep two columns always separate. At the smallest resolution, it does shift below but only after the images overlay.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="p-2">
            <img width="400" height="225" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <img width="120" height="67" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flex wrapped images aren’t overflowing the previous column – the image in your first column is intruding into the flex wrapped images’ space. Use `img-fluid` on the left-side image rather than defining a width and height to have it stay in its own column.

You can also use `img-fluid` for the small images on the right, rather than specifying the width and height, and you could use `row row-cols` to have the images wrap, rather than `flex-wrap` (row has `flex-wrap`).

```css
.img-padding {
    padding-bottom: 1.875rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid pt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 img-padding">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-4">
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
                <div class="col img-padding">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did add a custom padding class to add 1.875rem (30px) to the bottom of each image to get the same spacing between the rows of images as the space between the columns.

My example is setup with `container-fluid` – If you adjust the width of your browser window, you'll see the images change size.